# How to get rid of the notification bar glitch on the iPhone 4s if your lock button is broken?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4s has the notification bar glitch, and I've been researching on how to fix it. Most of the people said to restart the phone by pressing the home button and lock button at the same time. But my lock button is broken!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Assistive Touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658) to mimic the broken button.

Once you enable it (in Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Assistive Touch), to turn the phone off, you would activate the assistive touch menu, press "Device", and then press and hold "Lock Screen".

To turn the phone back on, plug it in to a power source (battery, wall socket, or computer).

Comment: I did that, and it still wouldn't shut down.

Comment: It takes a few seconds for "Lock Screen" to change to the "slide to power off" screen.  It has worked for me since my lock button broke in the same way.  What OS version is on your iPhone?

Comment: Ok, I see it, but I'm not able to slide it due to the notification bar is still in the way and it won't slide.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! My phone officially works now. I just had to wait for the battery to run low.

Answer (score 0):

Let your phone die and then plug it in to restart it.